# Find - как вывести результат выполнения команды в директорию?

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Всем привет. Столкнулся с задачей, к которой не знаю как подступиться.
Мне нужно было написать небольшой скрипт со следующим функционалом:

1) Найти все файлы, у которых нет пользователя ( Решил с помощью использования использования команды "find /home/user -nouser").
2) Найденные файлы необходимо складировать в определенный каталог.Но, не соображаю как найденные файлы поместить в определенный каталог.Хелп)
Суть вопроса: Как сделать так, чтобы полученный вывод командой FIND (Показывает список файлов) был перемещен в отдельный каталог в виде копий этих файлов.

Извините за использование скринов. иначе не могу.

Условный пример: после выполнения команды "find . -nouser" вывод будет примерно следующий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после выполнения скрипта хочу получить в отдельной папке вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приложение:
Для выведения простого листа использую следующую первоначальную[image: введите сюда описание изображения] конструкцию. Не знаю как ее изменить, чтобы получить нужный мне результат не в виде текста, а в виде копий реальных файлов в отдельной директории)

Comment: 1. противоречие между заголовком и содержимым. синхронизируйте, пожалуйста, нажав [edit]. 2. перемещаются файлы, как всегда и везде, программой mv.

Comment: Изменил, спасибо за замечание. Не могли бы вы ознакомиться со прикрепленным скрином? Я понял, что можно использовать mv, но могу ли я комбинировать данные команды таким образом, чтобы получаемые на выводе файлы я сразу перемещал в директорию. Извините за глупые вопросы и туфту)

Comment: 1. перечитайте, пожалуйста, свой вопрос **ещё раз**. что именно вы спрашиваете? 2. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @VenutTV Я что-то не пойму, а почему нельзя просто заменить *printf " %s\n" $item* на команду пересылки *mv $path1/$item  КудаНадо* ?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему,прикладываю ссылку на статью.
[Тут есть полезный комментарий](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241625/find-and-copy-files)

Задачу элементарно можно было решить одним объединением команд:

> *"find /home -nouser -exec sudo chown user1 {} \;"*

Таким образом все найденные файлы без пользователя(или пользователь удален) примут owner user1.

Но, было бы слишком неинтересно так, поэтому я написал костыль, где использую папку-посредник между двумя этими командами (Простите за unskill)
А так же приложу код, вдруг кому пригодится)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Script version 0.1"
echo "Введите пароль su:###"
echo "MANUAL: для выполнения определенных функций введите соотвествующую цифру"
echo "      "
echo "1)Вывести список файлов, владельцами которых являются удаленные пользователи."
echo "2)Скопировать все файлы,у которых нет пользователя, из определенного каталога в заданный каталог."
echo "3)Рекурсивная смена пользователя по каталогу "
echo "Ведите идентификатор команды:"
funt1=1
funt2=2
funt3=3
read command
echo "Запрос с номером:" $command " принят в обработку"




function nouser(){
echo "Введите путь ниже "
read path1
declare -a nousersS=($(find $path1 -nouser))
echo"Вывод будет в фалйе fly.txt"
echo ${#nousersS[*]}
for item in ${nousersS[*]}
do
printf "%s\n" $item
done
}




function copytodir(){
echo "Введите путь, где искать файлы без пользователя"
read path2
echo "Путь поиска: " $path2
sleep 3
echo "Введите путь до места, куда сложить данные файлы"
read path3
echo "Файлы будут находиться по пути: " $path3
sleep 3
find $path2 -nouser -exec cp -n {} $path3 \;
echo "Лог находится в fly2.txt"
sleep 10
}





function chowner(){
echo "Введите путь для рекурсивной смены пользователя по всей директории"
read path4
echo "Выбранна директория: " $path4
sleep 5
echo "Введите нужого пользователя"
read usr
#echo "введите нужную группу"
#read grp
chown -R $usr $path4
}



if [[ $command == $funt1 ]];
then
echo "Вызов функции " #$command
nouser
fi

if [[ $command == $funt2 ]];
then
echo "Вызов функции " #$command
copytodir
#find . -nouser -exec cp -n {} /home/babach/Общедоступные/отдельнаяпапка \;
fi

if [[ $command == $funt3 ]];
then
echo "Вызов функции " #$command
chowner
fi
```